# jaxb Unmarshaller : repeated xmlelement without wrapper

Tags: jaxb, jackson

```xml
<a>
    <b1>b1</b1>
    <b2>b2</b2>
    <b3>
        <c1></c1>
        <c2></c2>
    </b3>
    <b3>
        <c1></c1>
        <c2></c2>
    </b3>
    <b3>
        <c1></c1>
        <c2></c2>
    </b3>
</a>
```

Since all the `<b3>` are not included in a wrapper element, say `<b3s>` when I use Jackson `XmlMapper` to read the XML file to my POJO Java Bean class, I got exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.xxxxx] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.xxxx["xxx"]->com.xxx["xxx"])
```

What annotation shall I use?

```java
@XmlElement
public List<B3> b3;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use "unwrapped" representation, you need to use Jackson 2.1, and indicate unwrapped option:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
```

alternatively, if using JAXB annotations, default should be not to use wrapping.

Finally, you can also change the default not to use wrapper element, with:

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
// to default to using "unwrapped" Lists:
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
```

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE**

Jackson is not a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) compliant implementation. This means there are no guarantees on how it interprets the standard JAXB annotations

---

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) compliant implementation does not apply a wrapper element to collection properties.

**A**

By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will default mappings based on the properties.  To save space I have omitted those methods and specified `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` so that the metadata will be derived from the instance variables (fields).

```java
package forum13097559;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private List<B3> b3;

}
```

**B3**

```java
package forum13097559;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B3 {

    private String c1;
    private String c2;

}
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum13097559;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13097559/input.xml");
        A a = (A) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(a, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>
    <b1>b1</b1>
    <b2>b2</b2>
    <b3>
        <c1></c1>
        <c2></c2>
    </b3>
    <b3>
        <c1></c1>
        <c2></c2>
    </b3>
    <b3>
        <c1></c1>
        <c2></c2>
    </b3>
</a>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does not know how to turn a string into an instance of `B3`. Add a constructor (or factory method which returns a `B3`) to `B3` which takes a single `String`. Constructor example:

```
class B3 {
    // ...
    public B3(String value) {
       // do something with value 
    }
    // ...
}
```

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureCreators